# Multiple SQLiteOpenHelper implementations but only one class's oncreate is getting called

Tags: android, sqlite

I have implemented multiple `SQLiteOpenHelper` class for the same database same version.
(my1SQLiteOpenHelper class, my2SQLiteOpenHelper class, my3SQLiteOpenHelper class)

I have put create tables sql statement in  `oncreate` and `onupgrade` methods for all classes

When i run... only **my1SQLiteOpenHelper** class `oncreate` method is called. any other classes oncreate or onupgrade is Not getting called.

so i'm getting table missing error.

1) Any idea why this is happening..?

2) Is it possible to use upgrade a existing database from another instance of **my2SQLiteOpenHelper** ?

3) Can you force run `onUpgrade` method ?

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` manages database files by name and version number. The first one brings your database file to the given version. The rest have nothing left to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: i tried adding "getWritableDatabase()" but it does make any difference also tried changing versions.  i'm trying to add new tables to existing database, using another  new `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation. then which method is called `Oncreate()` or `onupgrade()`? 
In my case non of them are getting called, and a error comes saying table missing.

Comment: Use only one `SQLiteOpenHelper` per database.

Comment: ok,thanks 
can you unmark duplicate